# How to consistently access whether a user is authenticated in view

Tags: node.js, express, pug, passport.js

I'm trying to restrict user access to content in an express app using passport.js as authentication middleware. The way I'd like to do this is by loading all restricted views into a block in a base template using pug.js template inheritance:

```
// All views extend this base template
doctype html
html
   head
   body
      h1 This is my base template
      if(authenticated)
         // Child templates overwrite this block with their content
         block content
      else
         // Otherwise, prompt user to log in
         a(href='/login') login
```

I've read that I can access values saved in res.locals in the view, but such values are scoped to that response and I'll have to pass a value like 'authenticated: true' to every template I end up rendering using the above method.  Is there a better way to consistently access session data across all views without code duplication or perhaps a better way to approach restricting user access in express apps in general?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you should not have to reset `authenticated` to be true every time the template is rendered. Pug will pass any variables you specify to the template without getting in the way of their values. The innards of your route need to pass the `authenticated` variable after you determine whether or not someone actually is authenticated.

**route.js**

```
var authenticated = true; // However you determine authenticated to be true or false
res.render('/yourpage', {
    authenticated: authenticated
});
```

Your Pug code would remain the same. If authenticated is true, the user can see that content. If not, they'll be prompted to log in.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, I've edited the question to be more specific.  What I meant was, I'd like to be able to be able access the authenticated user from any view without having to explicitly pass them into every response.  What I'm looking for is essentially a global session object that I can access in the view.